# Does Easton forcing preserve measurable cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals

The question is in the title. For Easton's theorem see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem). Loosely speaking we can use forcing to manipulate the powerset function on regular cardinals as much as we like given we satisfy the following restrictions: (a) $\kappa<\lambda$ implies $2^\kappa\le 2^\lambda$ and (b) $\kappa<cf(2^\kappa)$.

In addition, Easton's forcing preserves cardinals.

**Question**: Does Easton forcing preserve measurable cardinals? In particular, if $\mu$ is the first measurable, does it remain the first measurable in the extension (measurable here means "there is an $\aleph_1$-complete non principal ultrafilter on $\mu$).
If the answer is "no" does the restriction of Easton's theorem below the first measurable $\mu$ preserve  the measurability of $\mu$?

Comment: Presumably you don't intend to let Easton blow up the continuum (or power sets of other cardinals below $\mu$) past $\mu$, because that would certainly destroy its measurability.

Comment: A slightly less trivial comment: GCH cannot first fail at a measurable cardinal. So if $\mu$ is the first cardinal whose power set's cardinality you increase, you'll destroy its measurability.

Comment: @AndreasBlass. Yes, I don't want to blow any cardinals below $\mu$ to larger than $\mu$. The second comment is indeed worth knowing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a variety of positive and negative results on this topic, depending on the Easton function and the set-theoretic background.

The Kunen-Paris theorem, for example, provides a large number of positive instances.

**Theorem.** If $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal and $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$, then for any Easton function $E:A\to\kappa$ defined on a set $A\subset\kappa$ of regular cardinals below $\kappa$, with $A\notin\mu$ for some normal measure $\mu$ on $\kappa$, then in the Easton forcing extension $V[G]$, the cardinal $\kappa$ remains measurable.

**Proof.** Let $\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\P$ be the Easton forcing for $E$, and suppose that $G\subset\P$ is $V$-generic. Let $j:V\to M$ be the ultrapower by $\mu$. If you consider $j(\P)$, you can factor it at $\kappa$ and see that $j(\P)=\P\times\P^*$, where $\P^*$ is the forcing beyond stage $\kappa$. There is no forcing at coordinate $\kappa$ precisely because $\kappa\notin j(A)$. It follows that $\P^*$ is $\leq\kappa$-closed in $M$. Furthermore, the size of $\P^*$ is $|j(\kappa)|^M$, and so the number of subsets of it in $M$ is $|j(2^\kappa)|^M=|j(\kappa^+)|^M$, and this is $\kappa^+$ in $V$, since $(\kappa^+)^\kappa=\kappa^+$. So in $V$ we may line up the dense subsets of $\P^*$ in $M$ into a $\kappa^+$ sequence. Since $M^\kappa\subset M$, we may therefore perform a diagonalization to build in $V$ an $M$-generic filter $G^*\subset\P^*$, simply by meeting the dense sets one-by-one. Since $G$ is $V$-generic, it is also $M[G^*]$-generic, and so $G\times G^*$ is $M$-generic for $j(\P)$. This filter fulfills the lifting criterion, and so we may lift the embedding to $j:V[G]\to M[j(G)]$, with $j(G)=G\times G^*$. Thus, $\kappa$ remains measurable in $V[G]$, as desired. 
$\Box$

Note that the assumption $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ can be easily forced without adding subsets to $\kappa$ and thefore while preserving the measurability of $\kappa$. So the argument is applicable to any measurable cardinal, whether or not the GCH holds at $\kappa$, provided one also forces $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$.

Since the construction of $G^*$ has wide flexibility, there are many such $G^*$ and consequently it follows that in $V[G]$ there are $2^{2^\kappa}$ many normal measures on $\kappa$. This is how Kunen and Paris proved the consistency of having many normal measures on a measurable cardinal.

There are many similar further such lifting arguments in many of my papers, but let me point you to:

- *Hamkins, Joel David*, [**Destruction or preservation as you like it**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/asyoulikeit/), Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 91, No. 2-3, 191-229 (1998). [DOI:10.1016/S0168-0072(97)00044-4](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0168-0072(97)00044-4), [ZBL0949.03047](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0949.03047), [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/asyoulikeit/).

Using results in that paper, one can show that $\kappa$ is not necessarily the least measurable cardinal in $V[G]$, since it could be that the measurability of some smaller cardinal is turned on by the forcing.

The general case of $A\in\mu$ is not always possible, since if you control some pattern of the continuum function on a set $A$ of measure one, this will have consequences for the continuum function at $\kappa$ itself in $M$. And so the general rule is that the function $E$ must exhibit certain kinds of self-reference in order to be able to preserve the large cardinal property at $\kappa$.

Another limitation or negative result is that the consistency strength of $\kappa$ is measurable plus $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$ is strictly stronger than a measurable cardinal. One needs $\kappa$ to be $\kappa^{++}$-tall. (See my paper, 
*Hamkins, Joel D.*, [**Tall cardinals**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/tallcardinals/), [Doi:10.1002/malq.200710084](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.200710084), Math. Log. Q. 55, No. 1, 68-86 (2009). [ZBL1165.03044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1165.03044), [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/tallcardinals/).) So it will be necessary to start with a larger large cardinal situation if this is desired.

Meanwhile, one can achieve a large number of positive instances when one begins with a supercompact cardinal. In many of these cases it is often easier to use the Easton-support iteration rather than the Easton product forcing.

There is a whole literature on combining Easton's theorem with large cardinals, and perhaps people can post further references. Let me mention a few papers of Brent Cody, who first looked at this topic in his disseration (under my supervision).

- *Cody, Brent*, [**Easton’s theorem in the presence of Woodin cardinals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00153-013-0332-0), Arch. Math. Logic 52, No. 5-6, 569-591 (2013). [ZBL1305.03039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1305.03039).
- *Cody, Brent; Friedman, Sy-David; Honzik, Radek*, [**Easton functions and supercompactness**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm226-3-6), Fundam. Math. 226, No. 3, 279-296 (2014). [ZBL1341.03069](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1341.03069).
- *Cody, Brent; Gitman, Victoria*, [**Easton’s theorem for Ramsey and strongly Ramsey cardinals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2015.04.006), Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 166, No. 9, 934-952 (2015). [ZBL1371.03064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1371.03064).

Comment: Every time I ask here on MO, a new window opens and the view is always a lot nicer and a lot wider than I thought. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your welcome! It was a pleasure, and this is a very nice topic, which I find to be very rich with mathematical ideas.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $GCH$ holds, $U$ is a normal measure on $\kappa$ and $j: V \to M$ is an ultrapower embedding.

Let $F$ be an Easton function on regular cardinals and $P_F$ be the corresponding Easton forcing. Also let $G_F$ be $P_F$-generic filter.

First note that we can assume that $dom(F)$ contains regular cardinals $\leq \kappa$ (as the rest is $\kappa^+$-closed and does not have any effects on measurability of $\kappa$).

If $\kappa \notin dom(j(F)),$ then $\kappa$ remains measurable in $V[G_F].$ This is due to Kunen-Paris: *[Boolean extensions and measurable cardinals](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843%2871%2990001-5)*, Annals of Mathematical Logic **2** Issue 4 (1971) pp 359-377.

Also if we force with $Add(\lambda, 1)$
for all regular $\lambda < \kappa$, then $\kappa$ fails to be measurable in $V[G_F].$ See pages 375-376 of the above paper of Kunen-Paris  (the argument works if we also  force at  all regular $\lambda \leq \kappa$).

Comment: Than you for the reference to Kunen-Paris. You answer the question too. I marked Joel's answer, because it came first and it is very detailed.

Comment: Actually, Ioannis, Mohammad's answer came slightly before mine. I was finishing my writing when he posted his answer.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins  Strange! When I click the "oldest" tab, your answer appears first.